# How to call a function from base class and derived class both?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am writing a simple piece of code.

```
class A
 {
   public:
   virtual func ()
    { // allocate memory 
    }
 };

class B : public A
 {
   public:
   func ()
    { // some piece of code
      // but call base class same function Ist 
    }
 }

 main()
    {
      A *ptr = new B;
      ptr->func () //here I want to call base class function first 
                   //and then derived class function
                   // How to implement ??
    }
```

1. How to call base class function first and then call same function from derived class ??.
   I dont want to call each function explicetly, I will just call derived class function   and the base class function should be automatically called.
2. I dont want any constructor to call these functions.
3. Is there any way to implement this or this is all rubbish.

Comment: I have fixed some obvious errors in the syntax. Remember to use *working* code for questions, otherwise the errors in the question might hide the issues you want to ask about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the method `func` of the parent class (you need to do this explicitly) in the implementation of `B`:

```
class B: public A
{
    public:
    func()
    {
        A::func();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont wish to change any of the functions

Comment: You could try praying, but I doubt it helps. You'll have to change the implementation of B to call A for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `A::func()` explicitly.

```
class B : public A
 {
  public:
   void func ()
    {
      A::func(); // call base class func()
      // some more code 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I dont wish to change any of the functions

Answer (score 1):

You can't arrange for it to happen automatically; you'll have to call the base-class function from the derived-class override:

```
void B::func() {
    A::func(); 
    // then do something else
}
```

Comment: I dont wish to change any of the functions

Comment: @user1160090: That's unfortunate, since you're going to have to change something.